# ValidationError HTTP Code for 'user already exist'

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a login app for my Django project using Django Rest Framework.

At registration, in my serializer, i'm checking if user already exist by doing this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    """                                                                                               
    Create an user but validate datafirst(checking if exist,                                          
    if mail is right,not already in-use, and hash password).                                          
    """
    queryset = PictureUser.objects.filter(username=validated_data['username'])
        try:
            queryset[0]
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The username is already used.')
        except IndexError:
            print ("User don't exist.")
            user = PictureUser.objects.create(
                email = validated_data['email'],
                username = validated_data['username'],
                password = make_password(validated_data['password']),
            )
            user.save()
            return user
```

This work pretty well. But the HTTP code sent is `400` when the user already exist. How can I change it to `409` or `422` to be more accurate on what went wrong ? (400 error would imply many other errors.)

Must I return an HttpResponse instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in the serializer.

Maybe you can have something like this:

`view.py`

```
class YourView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = YourSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'yourinfo':'something'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT) # change it to
```

`serializer.py`

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # Override this if you want. Default Django Auth
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
    def validate(self, attrs):

        username = attrs['username']
        password = attrs['password']

        # do your validations here

        if everything_ok:
            return attrs
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User does not belong to API group")
```

Comment: Ok thanks I see how I should handle this. I'm just editing your snippet for the "everithing".